# Pandas read_csv returns too many rows when using skiprows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file containing a header and 12 653 750 rows of data. I would like to use pandas to read the header and last 2 653 750 rows. In other words, I would like to skip the first 10 000 000 rows of data and by using this code:

```
part_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows=range(1, 10000001), index_col=False)
```

So I would expect pandas to return a dataframe with a header and 2 653 750 rows of data. However, what I get from pandas is a dataframe with a header and 5 123 000 rows of data, which should not be possible. Funny enough, when I tried `skiprows=range(1, 20000001)` pandas still returns a dataframe (without any errors), but now with 123 000 rows, even though the full data does not contain that many rows.

I tried the same code on a quite small data set with 50 rows and there it works perfectly. Any idea what could be the reason for this odd behaviour and most importantly how to work around this problem?

Just to say it up front, I am fully aware of other packages such as vaex, or Dask (which at some point drove me mad), but I wanted to make this simple process work with pandas.

Comment: What happens if you look at the head/tail of the imported df? Are the imported rows full rows? Or is it splitting your rows after some column?

Comment: Seems like a bug.  You could try `Dictreader` from the csv module instead and then convert the results into a Dataframe.

Comment: @noah Thanks for your suggestion. I just checked and both `.head()` and `.tail()` return rows with data (non-empty). To double-check, I also opened the file with a large file viewer software and I found out that every other row in my CSV file was empty from row 5 061 501 and on. Since `.read_csv` uses parameter `skip_blank_lines=True` by default (I wasn't aware of this) I get exactly the number of rows as expected when loading the full data. But it seems that this doesn't work well when using the `skiprows` argument.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Thank you for your suggestion. I'll keep this option in mind.